# tkinter animation speed on windows and linux

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to create simple 2d game using tkinter, but faced with interesting problem: animation speed is quite different on various computers.

To test this, I've create script, that measures time of animation

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

root = tk.Tk()

can = tk.Canvas(height=500, width=1000)
can.pack()

rect = can.create_rectangle(0, 240, 20, 260, fil='#5F6A6A')


def act():
    global rect, can
    pos = can.coords(rect)
    if pos[2] < 1000:
        can.move(rect, 5, 0)
        can.update()
        can.after(1)
        act()
  

def key_down(key):
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    act()
    print(datetime.datetime.now() - t)
    

can.bind("<Button-1>", key_down)
root.mainloop()
```

and get these results:
i3-7100u ubuntu 20.04 laptop python3.8.5 - 0.5 seconds
i3-7100u windows 10 laptop python3.9.4 - 3 seconds
i3-6006u ubuntu 20.10 laptop python3.9.x - 0.5 seconds
i3-6006u windows 10 laptop python3.8.x - 3 seconds
i5-7200u windows 10 laptop python3.6.x - 3 seconds
i5-8400 windows 10 desktop python3.9.x - 3 seconds
fx-9830p windows 10 laptop python3.8.x - 0.5 seconds

tkinter vesrion is the same - 8.6

How can be it fixed or at least explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkinter.Canvas.after` should be used like so:

```py
def act():
    global rect, can
    pos = can.coords(rect)
    if pos[2] < 1000:
        can.move(rect, 5, 0)
        can.update()
        can.after(1, act)
```

The after method is not like `time.sleep`. Rather than recursively calling the function, the above code schedules it to be called later, so this will break your timing code.

If you want to time it again, try this:

```py
def act():
    global rect, can, t
    pos = can.coords(rect)
    if pos[2] < 1000:
        can.move(rect, 5, 0)
        can.update()
        can.after(1, act)
    else:
        print(datetime.datetime.now() - t)
  

def key_down(key):
    global t
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    act()
```

This may still take different amounts of time on different machines. This difference can be caused by a variety of things like CPU speed, the implementation of tkinter for your OS etc. The difference can be reduced by increasing the delay between iterations: `tkinter.Canvas.after` takes a time in milliseconds, so a delay of `16` can still give over 60 frames per seconds.

If keeping the animation speed constant is important, I would recommend you use [delta time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing) in your motion calculations rather than assuming a constant frame rate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but using can.after() like this cause another problem: combination moving (to the right side, than to bottom) doesn't work correctly

Comment: This is the correct way to use `can.after()`. It sounds like you have another problem, so please create a new question for this problem, or edit this question if it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

AS you can see from your data it doesent matter which python version. It appears that ubuntu systems can help process python easier. However, im pretty sure its just the processer or how much ram the computer has.

Comment: I've tried testing on laptop with dual-boot linux and windows, so configuration was the same, but results differs.